# How to vertically align navbar-items in bootstrap 5.3 navbar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The navbar is currently transparent, but when you scroll down, it has a white background. now in the white background, it is not vertically centered. I'd appreciate recieving the solution as a url in codepen

Code:

```
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">


          <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg p-md-3 navbar-text-white d-flex">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Web Zone</a>
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
          aria-controls="navbarNav"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <div class="mx-auto"></div>
          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
<script>
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
      if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
        nav.classList.remove("navbar-text-white");
        nav.classList.add('bg-light', 'shadow', 'navbar-text-black');
      } else {
        nav.classList.add("navbar-text-white");
        nav.classList.remove('bg-light', 'shadow', 'navbar-text-black');
      }
    });
</script>
```

I tried multiple things in order to fix this  like seeing from other stackoverflow posts but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add this css:

```
nav .container {
padding-bottom: 0;
}
```